# Transform second order IVP to first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, initial-value-problems

> IVP is given by:
>   $$y''(t)= \dfrac{1}{1+t} \\
> y(0)= y'(0)=0
> $$

Need to transform this IVP into 
$$x'(t)=Ax(t)+b(t) , x(0)=0  \tag 1 $$

I am having some issues with this specific question. I am able to transform other higher ODE's into first order systems.
If anyone could explain how I can **make a start** in getting it into the form (1) - that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \pmatrix {y\\ y'}'=\pmatrix { 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0    }   \pmatrix {y \\ y'}+ \pmatrix {0 \\ \dfrac 1 {t+1}}$$
Substitute $u=y$ and $v=y'$:

$$ \pmatrix {u \\ v}'=\pmatrix { 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0    }   \pmatrix {u \\ v}+ \pmatrix {0 \\ \dfrac 1 {t+1}}$$
$$X'=AX+B$$
With initial condition:
$$X(0)=\pmatrix {u(0) \\ v(0)}=\pmatrix {y(0) \\ y'(0)}=\pmatrix {0 \\ 0}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

You could take $x(t) = y'(t)$, so the equation becomes $x' = 1/(1+t)$.  This is $Ax + b(t)$ where $A = 0$.  Then to get $y$ you integrate:
$y(t) = \int_0^t x(s)\; ds$.